# Endpoints when adding assembly references?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF service that uses a reference to a class library. Classes in that library do things like interact with a database. I was testing my service (which compiles with no errors) using restful calls through a browser and it just displays a page that simply says "Endpoint not found.". I'm assuming that this is related to the fact that the library has references to connection strings and appsettings etc (which i normally have to include in the applications that use this library). So what I'm having trouble finding is how to properly configure the wcf service to work with this library. I tried simply adding the connection strings and appsetings to the wcf web.config but that doesn't seem to help. I feel like it is just about adding reference to the library through the endpoint section of the service. But I'm lost there. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">

        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

UPDATE:
Running the trace, this is the stack trace from the exception being thrown:

System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.HttpUnhandledOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

Comment: Endpoint not found is related to your WCF config, which you haven't provided.

Comment: updated. Apologies in advance if I seem vague. It is simply because I'm not exactly sure how to ask the question

Comment: I've not worked with wcf rest, so I'm not of much help, but you should probably also post your c# method definitions and the URL you are trying to load.

Comment: Not Found errors don't always mean not found.  If an exception occurs in the right spot in the service channel, you can get a "Not Found" exception.  Try turning on WCF tracing.  It is really verbose, so I don't recommend leaving it on, but it will give you plenty of details.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: There was an exception caught in the trace. however, it doesn't say what it really is, just System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089. This error only occurs when the library is used by the service. I have no problems in other applications.

Comment: What happens when you use `address="/"` in your endpoint instead of `address=""` configuration?

Comment: If you remove reference to the library and just fake up some data does the service work then? Just trying to work out whether its a fundamental issue with your WCF setup or whether it really is interaction with the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I got it working. It APPEARED to be an issue with the host address. I recreated the project as a Service Library instead of a Service Application and I noticed a couple new fields in the default config. One of which was for the host. When I set the base address, everything started working just hunkydory. Here is the config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="ServiceWithLibraryTest.UtiService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceWithLibraryTest.IUtiService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />        
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/ServiceWithLibraryTest/UtiService/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I'm kind of new to WCF and from what I understand, it is notorious for the config constantly being a head scratcher. I'm still working on wrapping my head around endpoints, but I'm starting to get a better understanding of how endpoints are just the means of exposing the service and behaviors being how they are communicated. Then of course, rest services add a whole new layer to that. I appreciate the thoughts :)